# Determining a PHP script's execution time

Tags: php, cpu-usage

Lately I have gotten myself into a predicament. My system started consuming too much CPU and it turns out that along with a few SQL queries (that got logged in MySQL slow query log), there is also a number of PHP scripts that take too long to execute.

**Question is:** is there a way to determine the execution time of let's say 2000+ PHP scripts (how long it took to execute) without having to insert a snippet of code inside each and every one of them?

I was reading up on profiling but it does not seem the kind of thing I need. Thanks.

Comment: I do think that profiling is what you need here.  There are lots of options for PHPprofiling, most are free.  You might want to try xdebug: http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler which works well with the latest version of PHP and has a very nice GUI.  Note that no custom code needs to be inserted to profile so obtaining the info you need is quite simple.

Comment: If possible you could do a `time();` and write that to a file in your first script then a `time();` in your last script and write that to the same file again. Then calculate what the difference is between the 2.

Comment: I agree with shev72. Just because a script is taking too much time does not mean that it is using a lot of CPU, e.g. it could be doing some unexpected blocking. Also, figure out the smallest workload you can run and use that for profiling.